# Uniswap Router Remove Liquidity from one side of LP

Tags: solidity, uniswap, router

With the Uniswap Router is it possible to remove liquidity from one side of an LP? I know there is a function for providing liquidity to one side, but haven't been able to find a function for removing liquidity from one side. Also, would the contract which is executing this function have to have some balance of LP tokens?

Answer (score 0):

When you add liquidity to create a new position in Uniswap v3, you select a price range for that position. The price range remains constant for the lifetime of the position. Any subsequent calls to `addLiquidity` and `decreaseLiquidity` cannot change this price range.

If the current price of the pool is outside the price range of the position, then calling `decreaseLiquidity` will result in just one of the pool's tokens being made available for collection. This is because the whole position is on a single side of the price. There is no way how the caller can change this behavior, except by changing the price in the whole pool.